# Why are fishing rods prohibited in hand luggage when travelling by airplane in Europe?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security, prohibited-items, fishing

Can anyone explain why exactly we cannot take a cheap collapsible fishing rod in hand baggage? (Europe, e.g. UK and Spain)

I mean seriously, what am I going to do? poke someone gently from a distance?

Comment: Can you add a reference to the specific rule you're asking about?

Comment: Maybe because you could poke someone (accidentially) in the eye?

Comment: bizarre!  it looks like other "long thin" things are banned (pool cues and so on).  perhaps it's just because it looks like .. .could be .. a rifle???  it's a good question!

Comment: Might it simply be due to the shape and size of them - they're not going to fit in the overhead locker - although I'd expect that to be an airline restriction rather than a regulatory one...

Comment: No its a blanket ban - mine is only 18" long when collapsed so fits perfectly within carry-on baggage.

Comment: Years ago I always used to travel with a pair of rollerblades. I always brought them as hand luggage. I do forget if always in a smaller pack or just on their own. Then one day an airline wouldn't let me bring them on in case I unbolted all the wheels and tried to use the frame as a weapon. After that I always packed them in my checked luggage, where they took up a lot more of my backpack than I preferred. After that nothing surprises me with rules wrt hand luggage.

Comment: @hippietrail were your rollerblades actually challenged by the airline or at the airport security checkpoint?

Comment: @phoog: I forget now but I think it was the airline staff. I could be wrong, maybe it was at the x-ray machine area?

Comment: Have you asked the airline if a collapsible rod with no sharp edges is allowed ? A cursory search seems to point to airlines not security as the ones behind the requirement

Comment: Maybe because a fishing rod may well contain a sharp and weapon-worthy fishing hook? (This is pure speculation, I don’t want to turn this into an answer!)

Comment: Weirdly, I had my (€6) rod taken off me at security, BUT they didn't notice the row of hooks across the back of my bag!!!

Comment: Speculation, but rather than being worried about the resemblance of a fishing rod to something like a pool cue, perhaps they are worried about its potential resemblance to - a whip, switch, cane, or lash.  Also weapons, capable of hurting someone (though probably useful for pain moreso than damage, especially in tight quarters).   I don't know exactly how much your specific fishing pole resembles either, but the iconic fishing pole does share some similarities in form and motion.  Alternatively, when collapsed they might think it useable as a baton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you are not allowed to bring on board things that can be used to hurt someone or to hide something dangerous, and a foldable fishing rod fall into both categories at once, even if mostly in the first.

It's the same problem photographer can have with tripods and similar (and that I had once with an old lens). If you can take something on board and (reasonably) change it into a weapon (of sort)...it's a no no.

Think it this way: even if it's an annoyance, it's a way less annoyance than blowing up in mid-air or paying a really quick visit into a building.